# Record audio in C++ with best compression regardless of quality

Tags: c, winapi, audio, compression

I want to create a small app that records audio from the mic then save it with best compression, and I dont  care about sound quality ..I need the best compression ..i am recording human voice ..and I dont know where to start from ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good format for storing sounds on windows compressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136563/what-is-a-good-format-for-storing-sounds-on-windows-compressed)

Comment: I dont care about that the sound must be playable by windows ...i can create my own player or decompressor ..i just need compression ..

Comment: mp3 still very big for my needs ...

Comment: MP3 can go as low as 32Kbit/sec. What data rate do you need?

Comment: @RussellBorogove thats 14 mega per hour ...how can I get that rate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the LAME command line tool, apply the `--cbr -b 32` to achieve constant 32Kbit/sec, and you can replace the 32 with 24, 16, or 8 for lower rates. If you don't care about constant bit rate, you can get much better quality at a targeted average bit rate, with e.g. `--abr 32`. Here's a link to the LAME command line options: http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/doc/html/switchs.html

I would be very surprised if you could roll your own codec that performed better than MP3 for 8-32Kbit sec data rates.

Comment: I guess this is my need ..thanks alot, i will check it up

Answer (score 1):

Use [SPEEX](http://www.speex.org/) codec for voice or [OGG VORBIS](http://www.vorbis.com/) for general audio recording. Both formats are free and opensource. Moreover OGG VORBIS is better then MP3 at all bitrates.