# Getting bytes from GraphFilter SampleGrabber to Audio raw data WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow

I am having a big issue getting raw audio data from the SampleGrabber GraphFilter and writing it to an audio file in the proper format.

**What i'm trying to achieve is:**

1. grabbing the data from: **Microphone->SampleGrabber->Null Rendrer**
2. Write the raw data captured to a proper audio file (MP3\AVI\WAVE)

**Some questions:**

1. Am I setting the proper MediaType for the SampleGrabber?
2. How can you compress the audio data to a proper audio file?

**My current code below:**

```
struct sRecortdingData {
    std::vector<BYTE> recordingData;
    double totalRecordingTime;
};

class CFakeCallback : public ISampleGrabberCB
{
        public:
            sRecortdingData sRecording;
            STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef() { return 2; }
            STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release() { return 1; }

            STDMETHODIMP_(HRESULT __stdcall) QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
            {
                if (riid == IID_ISampleGrabberCB || riid == IID_IUnknown)
                {
                    *ppv = (void*) static_cast<ISampleGrabberCB*>(this);
                    return NOERROR;
                }
                return E_NOINTERFACE;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP_(HRESULT __stdcall) SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample* pSample)
            {
                return S_OK;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP_(HRESULT __stdcall) BufferCB(double SampleTime, BYTE* pBuffer, long BufferLen)
            {
                sRecording.recordingData.push_back(*pBuffer);
                sRecording.totalRecordingTime = SampleTime;
                return S_OK;
            }
};


void Microphone::RecordAudio()
{
    
    HRESULT hr;
    AM_MEDIA_TYPE mt;
    
    long recordingEventCode;
    IMediaControl* pMediaControl = NULL;
    ISampleGrabber* pISampleGrabber = NULL;
    IBaseFilter* pSampleGrabberFilter;
    IGraphBuilder* pGraphBuilder = NULL;
    IMediaEventEx* pEvent = NULL;
    IBaseFilter* pMicrophoneFilter = NULL;
    ISampleGrabber* pSampleGrabber = NULL;
    ICreateDevEnum* pDeviceEnum = NULL;
    IBaseFilter* pNullRender = NULL;

    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
       return;
    }

    // Filter graph
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraphBuilder));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }

    // Device enum
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDeviceEnum));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    // Null renderer
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NullRenderer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pNullRender));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }

    // Get the even control
    hr = pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEvent));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }

    // Sample Grabber
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSampleGrabberFilter));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }

    // Get Media Control
    hr = pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMediaControl));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }

    // Setup input device filter
    pMicrophoneFilter = Microphone::SetupDeviceFilter(CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory, pGraphBuilder, pDeviceEnum,
        Utils::s2ws("My Microphone");
    if (pMicrophoneFilter == NULL) {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    // Setup sample grabber filter
    pSampleGrabberFilter = Microphone::SetupDeviceFilter(CLSID_LegacyAmFilterCategory, 
        pGraphBuilder, pDeviceEnum, L"SampleGrabber");
    if (pSampleGrabberFilter == NULL) {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    // Connect both pins together
    Device_Connect(pMicrophoneFilter, pSampleGrabberFilter);

    // Setup null renderer filter
    pNullRender = Microphone::SetupDeviceFilter(CLSID_LegacyAmFilterCategory, 
        pGraphBuilder, pDeviceEnum, L"Null Renderer");
    if (pNullRender == NULL) {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    // Connect both pins together
    Device_Connect(pSampleGrabberFilter, pNullRender);


    // Get the ISampleGranner interface
    hr = pSampleGrabberFilter->QueryInterface(IID_ISampleGrabber, (LPVOID*)&pISampleGrabber);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
   
    hr = pISampleGrabber->SetCallback(&CB, 1);
    
    ZeroMemory(&mt, sizeof(mt));
    mt.majortype = MEDIATYPE_Audio;
    mt.subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_PCM;
    // Set the media type
    hr = pISampleGrabber->SetMediaType(&mt);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    pISampleGrabber->SetBufferSamples(FALSE);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    hr = pMediaControl->Run();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        HR_Failed(hr);
        return;
    }
    DWORD recordingTime = 20000;
    hr = pEvent->WaitForCompletion(recordingTime, &recordingEventCode);
    std::string str(CB.sRecording.recordingData.begin(), CB.sRecording.recordingData.end());

    // Do something with the data from callback and write it to audio file 
}
```

Comment: For more details about Sample Grabber Filter, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/sample-grabber-filter
About compress the audio data,you could refer to the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881787/record-audio-in-c-with-best-compression-regardless-of-quality

Comment: I have been to the docs many times, I need further help that's why I posted this..

Comment: The code snippet is not executable, so just a couple of comments to point you into right direction. `1` You want `SampleCB` callback, not `BufferCB`. `2` you wanted raw data and raw data is by design not a file, so these two are mutually exclusive `3` media type is set correctly for raw data `4` "compress" and "compress into file" are again insufficiently specific and contradict with your earlier intent. A rule of thumb is this: if you want so send over network then it can't be a file.

Comment: What I meant is how can you take the raw data (I know its not a file) , compress it, and write it to a compressed file? after it is retrieved from BufferCB?

Comment: How can you play the written raw data to a file and play it on a windows after you retrieve the data?

Comment: You could wrap this into a small buildable project and share it via github... This would make it easier to get feedback since the code you are showing could be actually executed.